# Rate of radiation of infra-red ray from a hot body?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, infrared-radiation

I have the equation $\frac{dE}{dt}=a(\tau^4-\tau_s^4)$ however I can't find anywhere what E is supposed to be. It is not pointed out anywhere in the text and what is confusing is that in engineering E was always Young's modulus.

Though the pages heading is Radiation of infra-red rays. Is E the radiation of infra-red rays?

Because I have another equation down the bottom saying that the equation $\frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T-T_s)$ was derived from it. I can't see the relation. It just looks like they have changed the letters.. without any meaning.

Comment: the second equation is Newton's Law of cooling, where $t$ is time, $T$ is temperature, and $T_s$ is temperature of surroundings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Stefan Boltzmann law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law). The quantity $dE/dt$ is (I quote from the link) *total energy radiated per unit surface area of a black body across all wavelengths per unit time*, so $E$ is indeed energy, and specifically total energy per unit area.